# How can I group items in Python so I can take the average of those grouped items?

Tags: python

I read the data below in from a .txt file and
saved it into a Python List object.
Below is some output for rows in that list object.

```
Year Month OtherValue
(1977, 10) 52
(1843, 9) 0
(1946, 6) 83
(1891, 3) 11
(2001, 5) 69
(1868, 7) 27
(1916, 9) 20
(1871, 10) 60
(1845, 3) 46
(1919, 12) 26
(1832, 8) 0
(1880, 2) 23
(1933, 8) 0
(2007, 1) 20
(1930, 11) 51
(1920, 3) 20
```

...

I need to group the rows by year, then by month.
Then compute the monthly average in a new column.
The year, month, and monthly average will be written
to a new .txt file with the following format:

```
Year Month Averages
2011 01    34.875
2011 02    29.897
2011 03    13.909
....
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Post your attempted code, please.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict`:

**Example:**

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lis = [(2011, 1, 50), (2012, 1, 5), (2011, 1, 35), (2012, 1,  15), (2013, 5, 37), (2011, 3, 45)]
>>> dic = defaultdict(lambda :defaultdict(list))
>>> for year, month, val in lis:
    dic[year][month].append(val)
...     
>>> dic
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x896afb4>,
{2011: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [50, 35], 3: [45]}),
 2012: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [5, 15]}),
 2013: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {5: [37]})})
```

Average for first month of 2011:

```
>>> sum(dic[2011][1])/float(len(dic[2011][1]))
42.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.sort()` to get the values in your list into the order by date, then use `itertools.groupby` to group them. It's made a little bit more tricky by the fact that `groupby` returns iterators, not lists (and so they don't have a `len`. But you can use a list comprehension to get the values you need pretty easily:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [(1977, 10, 52), (1977, 11, 20), (1977, 10, 0)] # example data

key = itemgetter(0, 1) # a callable to get year and month from data values
data.sort(key=key)
groups = [(date, [value for y, m, value in group]) for date, group in groupby(data, key)]
averages = [date + (sum(values) / len(values),) for date, values in groups]

# for example data, averages will be [(1977, 10, 26.0), (1977, 11, 20.0)]
```